# How to implement instagram stories in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, instagram

How can I implement Instagram Stories in Xamarin forms with C# ?

I've found this :

https://github.com/shts/StoriesProgressView

But it is with Java and it is for Android only

Comment: You will have to do a custom implementation like is the one you mentioned in the link. For Xamarin forms I am not aware of a library that achieves that so you can just import in your project.

Comment: @MihaiBC How can I do a custom implementation ?

Comment: The answer to this depends on how your project is structured but basically, you will have to create the view by yourself and also the logic behind it with the progress bar, animation, and everything else. I am aware that this also a generic answer but given the amount of information you provided this all I can come up with.

Comment: @MihaiBC I exactly want to implement instagram stories for my app users . My app exactly like instagram . I've implemented feeds and explore exactly like instagram , But I do not know how to implement stories

Comment: You could use Carousel Page in Forms . Then populate it with an image collection. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thank you a lot . Is Carousel Page has auto swipe ?

Comment: You could set a timer and change the current  index each x seconds .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you could use **CarouselView** to display the collection of Images .
It provides a scrollable layout where users can swipe to move through a collection of items.

it's currently experimental and can only be used by adding the following line of code to your **AppDelegate** class on iOS, or to your **MainActivity** class on Android, before calling **Forms.Init**:

```
Forms.SetFlags("CarouselView_Experimental");
```

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <CarouselView x:Name="carousel" IsSwipeEnabled="False" Position="{Binding Index}" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                        // I set BackgroundColor here just for demo and you need to set the Source of the Image
                        <Image BackgroundColor="{Binding .}" WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="500" Aspect="AspectFit"  />

                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public MainViewModel()
        {
            MySource = new ObservableCollection<Color>() {Color.LightBlue,Color.Red,Color.Yellow };

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),()=> {


                if(index<MySource.Count-1)
                {
                    Index++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Index = 0;
                }

                return true;
            
            });

        }
       

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

[image]